# How would I change '\t' with ' ' or ',' after reading in a .txt file with read.table()

Tags: r

Title pretty much sums it up, but I am just looking for help on how I can convert '\t' values into either '        ' or ','. I used sep = '\n' to keep format because I am going to write to a excel file.
Here is my code so far:

```
files <- list.files(path="example", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE) 
files

for(i in files){
  a <- read.table(i,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,sep = '\n',fill = TRUE,quote = '')
  print(a)
}
```

I have tried some methods like:

```
a <- gsub('\t', ',',a)
```

But nothing I have tried has been successful.

Comment: why don't you just do a <- readLines(i) ; then a <- gsub('\t', ',',a)

Comment: No worries. But I am a bit confused now. You have a txt file and you want to write it as csv?

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is their a way that I can now separate my data into different columns by the comma. Right each line is under the same column.

Comment: read.csv? or read.delim(.., sep=",") or can you just provide an example of your "txt" file? Do dput(readLines(files[1])) and paste the output as part of your question

Comment: Sorry I just rephrased my question haha. My goal is to turn a text file with no format other than tab spacing and have it fit into an excel file with each \t meaning go to the next cell. Now since I changed that to commas then I guess commas mean go to the next cell.

Comment: Excel would handle tabs in just the way you were hoping.